# HTML5 videos not playing on android chrome

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, video

I want to play HTML5 video on android chrome. As per specifications HTML5 videos dont autoplay  on mobile decides and user interaction is needed. 
For that, I have created an overlay with play button over video. On click of the video I have to some processing and then I call play on video element.

```
vid = $('<video id="video-elem"></video>');
vid.attr('src', "some.mp4");
vid.play();
```

On play, video has `readyState = 0`, because of this the video  doesn't play. 
I also tried catching `canplay` event of video which says that  video is ready to play. 
But if I try to play video by calling

```
vid.play()
```

Nothing happens. I also connected my device to chrome debugger and tried playing through console, but nothing works. Same thing works on iPad.
If I tap on the screen, on which I have called video play, then video starts playing.
Please suggest me some way to play video without second user interaction involved.

Thnaks.

Comment: I remember having similar kind of problems (on older iOS versions), which were solved by adding <source> element to <video>. Check: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/

Comment: I tried this. But isn't working for me.

Comment: I investigated more into this problem and observed that video duration is returned as 0 by browser on 'loadedmetadadata' event.